# How to connect to MongoDB without drivers in C#?

Tags: c#, mongodb

I want to create my own MongoDB driver but I don't find any document to connect to MongoDB server(like docker container) without exist drivers.
If it has socket, how to speak with that ?
If it has api, where is document ?
Or I should to use C shell driver ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to implement the [MongoDB Wire Protocol](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/mongodb-wire-protocol/). If any language implements this protocol then it's able to communicate with a MongoDB instance.

Microsoft did the same when they created the former DocumentDB to keep compatibility with MongoDB.

By the way, the Mongo Driver source code is also available, so you can learn a lot from it.  Link: [mongo-csharp-driver](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-csharp-driver)

I'm also thinking of implementing the same solution because I found something unfriendly in the driver. Please leave a comment what your purpose is for implementing the protocol.

Comment: I want to implement mongo driver can compatibility with elastic search and redis to give better performance to lookup and fetch data

Comment: I want to implement this driver in Golang(Because don't have official driver) or Node(Because have giant community), what's your idea ?